# Change the query being referenced by a function, depending on context

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a custom function in Access 2007 that hinges on grabbing data out of a specific query. It opens Outlook, creates a new email and populates the fields with specific addresses and data taken from the query `("DecisionEmail")`.
Now I want to make a different query `("RequestEmail")` to populate the email with that data. So all I have to do is change this line:

```
Set MailList = db.OpenRecordset("DecisionEmail")
```

This is my desired result: If the user is on `Form_Decision` and clicks the button `"Send email"`, `"DecisionEmail"` will get plugged into the function and that data will appear in the email. If the user on `Form_SendRequest` and clicks the button `"Send email"`, `"RequestEmail"` will get plugged in instead.

My last resort would be to make a new function and use the Conditions field in the Macro interface to choose between them.

I have a vague notion of setting the query names as variables and using an If statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not save the macro as code, then you can edit away to achieve say:

```
Function CustomEmail(NameOfQuery As String)

    CurrentDB.Openrecordset(NameOfQuery)

End Function
```

Then, on each form in the desired event:

```
CustomEmail "DecisionEmail"
```